# How to make One to one chat application using spring boot and websockets

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

Can anyone tell me "How to make One to one chat application using spring boot and websockets"
I had got an example using the below link for spring boot and websockets, in that the message is going to all the users who all had connected.
https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-websocket-chat-example/

I want to make the application like the chat between the client and the admin, The Conversation between each client and Admin must not go to other client .

Answer (score 0):

i realise you've probably moved on since but for the benefit of anyone else

one simple way is to have the client read the recipient from the message and decide if the message is intended for them. In your chatMessage model add fields for sender and recipient. Then on the client you would have something like

```
// RECIPIENT IS ME OR IS NULL THEN MESSAGE IS FOR ME (NULL BEING EVERYONE)
if (chatMessage.recipient === this.userName || chatMessage.recipient == NULL) 
   { 
    show the message 
} else 
{ 
    ignore it 
}
```

Alternatively you could create queues for each user. Someone forked it https://github.com/ddycai/spring-boot-chatrooms on github and did a version with multiple chatrooms, so you could use that as an example.